# nodejs redis connection recovery (when server is running)

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I use nodejs and [redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis) library to initiliaze the client.

I want to ask you how to handle redis connection in some scenarios. When server start, i know there is a retry configuration option. I configure 10 attempts and a wait time between each attempt.

My doubt is what'is the best way to recover the connection once the server is running. For example, the server start and connect succesful to redis client but after that my redis-server fall down. How can i recover the connection without restart the server?

Here my redis/client.js file. If you have any recommendation about this implementation for a real application, it is welcome!

```
'use strict';

const redis = require('async-redis');
var retryStrategy = require("node-redis-retry-strategy");

const client = redis.createClient(process.env.REDIS_PORT_DEV, process.env.REDIS_HOST_DEV, {
        retry_strategy: function(options) {
            if (options.total_retry_time > 1000 * 60 * 60) {
              // End reconnecting after a specific timeout and flush all commands
              // with a individual error
              strapi.log.error("ERR:REDIS: Retry time exhausted"); // ctx.log.info(folders);
              return new Error("Retry time exhausted");
            }

            if (options.attempt > 10) {
              // End reconnecting with built in error
              strapi.log.error("ERR:REDIS: Connection with REDIS failed after 10 attempts"); // ctx.log.info(folders);
              return undefined;
            }

            // reconnect after
            return Math.min(options.attempt * 100, 3000);
        }
    },
);

client.on("connect", function(time, args, rawReply) {
  strapi.log.info("Connected to Redis")
});

client.on("reconnecting", function (o) {
    strapi.log.info("Redis client reconnecting", o.attempt, o.delay);
});

client.on("end", function () {
    strapi.log.info("redis connection has closed");
});

client.on("monitor", function(time, args, rawReply) {
  strapi.log.info(time + ": " + args);
});

client.on('error', err => strapi.log.error('ERR:REDIS:', err));

const defaultExpirationTime = 6000; //second

module.exports = {

  async set(key, value, expirationTime){
    try{
        await client.setex(key, expirationTime || defaultExpirationTime, value);
    } catch (err) {
        strapi.log.error(`ERR:REDIS: Error in ${err.command} operation:`, err.code)
        return undefined;
    }
  },

  async fetch(key){
    try{
        return await client.get(key);
    } catch (err) {
        strapi.log.error(`ERR:REDIS: Error in ${err.command} get operation:`, err.code)
        return undefined;
    }
  },

  async clear(key){
    try{
        return await client.del(key);
    } catch (err) {
        strapi.log.error(`ERR:REDIS: Error in ${err.command} operation:`, err.code)
        return undefined;
    }
  },

}
```

Thanks!